# Increase dimension of a matrix in Python

Tags: python, data-science

I am working on increasing the dimension of matrix i.e adding 0th column of 1's. I have reshaped the 3*3 matrix and added the column of 1's on 1st column. Now when I multiply X(transpose)*X, it shows error i.e

Error:
"shapes (3,47,1) and (1,47,3) not aligned: 1 (dim 2) != 47 (dim 1)"

here is my code

```
import numpy as np
data= open("data2.txt","r")
x=[]
y=[]
```

oneslist=[]
    for i in range(47):
        oneslist.append(1)

```
rows=47
cols=2
a = [[0] * cols for i in range(rows)]
b= [[0] * 1 for i in range(rows)]

i=-1

for line in data:
    i=i+1
    xi,yj,z = line.split(",")
    #y.append(yj)
    if i<rows:
        for j in range(cols):
            if j==0:
                a[i][j] =  (xi)
                b[i][j]=   (z.strip())
            else:
                a[i][j]=   (yj)

a=np.array(a)

b=np.array(b)
z=np.array(oneslist)


pricevector=a[np.newaxis]        

pricevector = pricevector.reshape((1,pricevector.shape[1], 
pricevector.shape[2]))
pricevectorr=np.insert(pricevector,0,oneslist,2)

pricevectortranspose= pricevectorr.T

pricevectortranspose=np.array(pricevectortranspose, dtype = float)
pricevectorr=np.array(pricevectorr, dtype = float)
XtX=(pricevectortranspose).dot(pricevectorr)
```

Comment: The question starts off clear enough, but then your code sample throws it right off. You should try creating a [MCV example] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At the moment your question describes a 3x3 matrix but your code creates a 2x47 matrix `a`, and then gets weirder from there. You end up with a three-dimensional vector that you then transpose (which by default reverses the dimensions) and dot product. As the error says, you can't dot product a matrix that doesn't have corresponding row/column dimensions. It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes it is a 47*3 matrix and i took the transpose of it and multiplied the transposed matrix by real 47*3 matrix.

Comment: What makes you think it's a 47*3 matrix? I'm not sure how to convince you it's a 3D matrix. Try `pricevectorr.shape`.